# Health script to Check the services running in the Instance

Tags: shell, service

```
#!/bin/bash
function checkIt()
{
systemctl is-active --quiet $1
 if [ $? != 0 ]
 then
   echo $1 ":is bad";
 else
   echo $1 ":is good";
 fi;
}

checkIt "nginx"
checkIt "mysql"
checkIt "httpd.service"
checkIt "varnish"
checkIt "pure-ftpd.service"
checkIt "mariadb.service"
checkIt "sshd"
checkIt "named.service"
checkIt "crond.service"
```

Is this the right format to find the services running in a instance? Instead of using grep and ps commands.?
But the above program sometime leads to wrong output. Is there any solution for this.?

Comment: Please, post your observations of undesired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As exit status `$?` is an integer, use `ne` operator for comparing for numbers like `if [ $? -ne 0 ]`.

`!=` operator is used for string comparison.